# How to simplyfy this sql query?

Tags: sql-server, database

```
update Room set Selected = 1 where Room_ID = 
(select Room_ID from Room_Rev where Rev_ID = 
(select Rev_ID from Room_Rev where Room_ID = 'ROM0001'
and (Start_Date<='2015-03-20' and End_Date>'2015-03-20')))
```

Can someone help me to simplify this query?

I want to select many Room_ID from the Room_Rev where same Rev_ID with Room_ID = 'ROM0001', than the all Room_ID will be use to update Selected
Room and Room_Rev is one to many relationship

Comment: Finally I get the excutable query

Comment: update Room set Selected = 1 from Room join Room_Rev on Room.Room_ID = Room_Rev.Room_ID
where Room_Rev.Rev_ID = (select Rev_ID from Room_Rev where Room_ID = 'ROM0006'
and (Start_Date<='2015-03-20' and End_Date>'2015-03-20'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join like:

```
update r
set r.Selected = 1
from Room r 
inner join Room_Rev rr on r.Room_ID = rr.Room_ID
where rr.Room_ID = 'ROM0001'
and (rr.Start_Date<='2015-03-20' and rr.End_Date>'2015-03-20')
```

Comment: No, I want to select many Room_ID from the Room_Rev where same Rev_ID with Room_ID = 'ROM0001', than the all Room_ID will be use to update Selected = 1

Comment: I can see that you got the correct query finally. For next time, it will be good to put the table relations in your question.

Answer (score 1):

use a `join` in `Update...Select`:

```
update Room set Selected = 1 
from  
Room join Room_Rev rr on Room.Room_ID = rr.Room_ID and Room.Room_ID='ROM0001'
and Room.Start_Date<='2015-03-20' and Room.End_Date>'2015-03-20'
```

or use `where exists`:

```
update Room set Selected = 1 
where exisis (select Rev_ID from Room_Rev where Room_ID = 'ROM0001')
and Room_ID='ROM0001'
and (Start_Date<='2015-03-20' and End_Date>'2015-03-20')
```